# How can be solved java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, annotations

I`ve changed jdk to a 9 version in my project and then collided with an error :

```
Error:java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
```

I try to solve it by the adding following to pom.com but it wasn`t work for me:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
   <configuration>
       <!-- fork is needed so compiler args can be used -->
       <fork>true</fork>
       <compilerArgs>
           <arg>-J--add-modules</arg>
           <arg>-Jjava.annotations.common</arg>
       </compilerArgs>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Does it have other way to solve?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add an artifact containing the classes you need to the classpath.

It appears that the javax.annotation API is what you need.  See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2 for details.   You can add the following dependency to your project as any other and it should be present:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Remember to remove the compiler arguments!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It`s working. I was trying to find something same for hours when solution was so easy.

Comment: Basically think that the JRE has become smaller, and everything in javax.* you need to bring yourself

Comment: There is a Java 10 module containing the package javax.annotation.processing: `--add-modules java.compiler` . And yes, there is a hurdle replacing javax.annotation.Generated with javax.annotation.processing.Generated .

Comment: @Johannes Don't add module `java.compiler` just to get the [`javax.annotation.Generated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/Generated.html) annotation. Add the module containing the type, i.e. `java.xml.ws.annotation`

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen  When I add this dependency, I get an error " org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called"  during build.  Am I missing anything ?

Comment: @NeerajChand that is something else. Consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 14):

```
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
annotationProcessor("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
```

Comment: Please include more details in your answer instead of code only. Thanks!

Comment: I use Android Studio, and add this to build.gradle in the project's root directory. 


implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
annotationProcessor("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")

Answer (score 9):

From 2020 onwards, the javax.* modules have been transitioned to jakarta.
So the 2020+ proof dependency declaration is now:

```
<groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
```

See also [a blog with explanations](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) and [a complete table with old and new names](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jakarta_EE_Maven_Coordinates)

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue.
I was working with java8 while in bash_profile the version was java 11. changing that to java 8 worked.
Also, i tested in dummy project that the issue(when not version issue) is resolved using javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late, but I also met the same problem like this but other answers are all not working for me, as I'm running an Android project and it already has this in the build.gradle app file.

> implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

After several hours of research, I found the solution, which is add the following line below the above one:

> annotationProcessor("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")

Hopefully this can help.

Comment: Yes, annotationProcessor  works good

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and fixed by adding library javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar