# Getting error from comand line in android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated

Tags: android, android-databinding

While build android app from command line i am getting error Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated

I am enable dataBinding in android application

symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
/home/chetan/project/newGradle/app/build/generated/source/dataBinding/baseClasses/debug/com/sko/gradledemo/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {

symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
/home/chetan/project/newGradle/app/build/generated/source/dataBinding/baseClasses/debug/com/sko/gradledemo/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {

symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can be solved java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238014/how-can-be-solved-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-annotation-generated)

Comment: I am getting error when added dataBinding and build application from command line using ./gradlew assembleDebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this in my project when I used commandline `./gradlew :app:assembleDevDebug` but not when running my project in Android studio. Problem is that the annotation processing requery (dataBinding in your case) is failing with a dependency which was removed in newer JDKs.

My problem boiled down to Gradle using my "system" JDK which was `openjdk version "13.0.1"`. Even when setting `JAVA_HOME` to a specific one with JDK 8, Gradle was using the "system" one. This is easy to discover using `./gradlew -v` which printed `JVM: 13.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 13.0.1+9)`.

I solved this by setting the JDK home in my gradle.properties file in the root of the project to the JDK bundled with Android Studio.

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

After this the project run fine using commandline. Hope it helps others.