# Maven update in Java 9, Maven compile in Java 8 in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I have a project with Spring and Maven using Java version 8. When I run maven update it works with Java 9 or higher and when I compile it works well with Java 8. I have noticed this because updating with Maven changes a specific class to Java 9 and I cannot import this class.

The class is: javax.annotation.Generated (Java 8).

This is the class to import. However when I do a maven update the import of the file changes the class to:
javax.annotation.processing.Generated (Java 9 or higher) and the import fails.
When I compile the import of the class it goes back to javax.annotation.Generated

I have to say that I updated the project to the latest version of Spring a few days ago and now I have the problem.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must bring it yourself these days

Comment: I have tried to include that class in the pom but that does not work, maven update changes it to a higher version of Java and the import fails

Answer (score 0):

JDK/JRE has become smaller, and everything that is in `javax.*` we have to import ourself. Add this to your `pom` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried with that but it didn't work

Comment: Looks like you found my old comment to my old answer.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238319/53897

Comment: I think in my case jdk / jre has become higher

Comment: I have found a solution, I have changed the version of Spring from 2.6.0 to 2.5.3 and the problem has been solved