# NoClassDefFoundError for javax.security.RunAs when using Jakarta Annotations API 2.1.1 on Spring Boot 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-annotations

I am using spring boot 2.7 version and recently upgraded `jakarta.annotations-api.2.1.1` version. After this when I started application, I getting error like

```
No class deffounderror for javax.security.RunAs
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should'nt mix up packages. Each Spring Boot version has its tested dependencies which you should use. If you wanna use Jakarta then upgrade to Spring Boot 3+, otherwise stick with javax. Everything else is just painful.

Answer (score 0):

Javax API what you need to add.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238014/how-can-be-solved-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-annotation-generated).